# Translating Yul to Solidity

Tags: solidity, yul

I have this Yul function that I am trying to reverse to Solidity for learning purposes.
My results with the solidity function are different than the original functions and I don't see what I am missing.

Initial Yul function:

```
    function fpow(
        uint256 x,
        uint256 n,
        uint256 baseUnit
    ) internal pure returns (uint256 z) {
        assembly {
            switch x
            case 0 {
                switch n
                case 0 {
                    // 0 ** 0 = 1
                    z := baseUnit
                }
                default {
                    // 0 ** n = 0
                    z := 0
                }
            }
            default {
                switch mod(n, 2)
                case 0 {
                    // If n is even, store baseUnit in z for now.
                    z := baseUnit
                }
                default {
                    // If n is odd, store x in z for now.
                    z := x
                }

                // Shifting right by 1 is like dividing by 2.
                let half := shr(1, baseUnit)

                for {
                    // Shift n right by 1 before looping to halve it.
                    n := shr(1, n)
                } n {
                    // Shift n right by 1 each iteration to halve it.
                    n := shr(1, n)
                } {
                    // Revert immediately if x ** 2 would overflow.
                    // Equivalent to iszero(eq(div(xx, x), x)) here.
                    if shr(128, x) {
                        revert(0, 0)
                    }

                    // Store x squared.
                    let xx := mul(x, x)

                    // Round to the nearest number.
                    let xxRound := add(xx, half)

                    // Revert if xx + half overflowed.
                    if lt(xxRound, xx) {
                        revert(0, 0)
                    }

                    // Set x to scaled xxRound.
                    x := div(xxRound, baseUnit)

                    // If n is even:
                    if mod(n, 2) {
                        // Compute z * x.
                        let zx := mul(z, x)

                        // If z * x overflowed:
                        if iszero(eq(div(zx, x), z)) {
                            // Revert if x is non-zero.
                            if iszero(iszero(x)) {
                                revert(0, 0)
                            }
                        }

                        // Round to the nearest number.
                        let zxRound := add(zx, half)

                        // Revert if zx + half overflowed.
                        if lt(zxRound, zx) {
                            revert(0, 0)
                        }

                        // Return properly scaled zxRound.
                        z := div(zxRound, baseUnit)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My Solidity function:

```
    function fpowSol(
        uint256 x,
        uint256 n,
        uint256 baseUnit
    ) public pure returns (uint256 z) {
        if(x == 0) {
            if(n == 0) {
                return (baseUnit);
            } else {
                return (0);
            }
        }

        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            z = baseUnit;
        } else {
            z = x;
        }

        uint256 half = baseUnit >> 1;

        for(n >>= 1; n > 0; n >>= 1) {
            uint256 xx = x * x;
            if(xx / x != x) { require(false, "xx overvlowed"); }

            uint256 xxRound = xx + half;
            if(xxRound < xx) { require(false, "xxRound overflowed"); }

            x = xxRound / baseUnit;

            if(n % 2 == 0) {
                uint256 zx = z * x;
                require(zx / x == z, "zx overflowed");

                uint256 zxRound = zx + half;
                if(zxRound < zx) { require(false, "zxRound overflowed"); }

                z = zxRound / baseUnit;
            }
        }
        return (z);
    }
```

How would you rewrite this Yul function in solidity

or

Where am I wrong in my translation from Yul to solidity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I wasn't able to get the same result is because of the last `if` statement which was misleading to me

```
                    // If n is even:
                    if mod(n, 2) { ... }
```

Actually this is not `if(n%0 != 0)` and is in reality "if n is not even".

I'm new to yul so correct me if I'm wrong but I have been able to get consistent results to the main function and also to my calculation off chain. I assume this answer is correct.

Real function is

```
    function fpowSol(
        uint256 x,
        uint256 n,
        uint256 baseUnit
    ) public pure returns (uint256 z) {
        if(x == 0) {
            if(n == 0) {
                return (baseUnit);
            } else {
                return (0);
            }
        }

        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            z = baseUnit;
        } else {
            z = x;
        }

        uint256 half = baseUnit >> 1;

        for(n >>= 1; n > 0; n >>= 1) {
            uint256 xx = x * x;
            if(xx / x != x) { require(false, "xx overvlowed"); }

            uint256 xxRound = xx + half;
            if(xxRound < xx) { require(false, "xxRound overflowed"); }

            x = xxRound / baseUnit;

            if(n % 2 != 0) { // THIS HAS CHANGED
                uint256 zx = z * x;
                require(zx / x == z, "zx overflowed");

                uint256 zxRound = zx + half;
                if(zxRound < zx) { require(false, "zxRound overflowed"); }

                z = zxRound / baseUnit;
            }
        }
        return (z);
    }
```